# Loading Latex packages into Mathematica

Tags: formatting, latex

Is it possible to specify a latex package to load while pasting TeX expressions into Mathematica notebooks. For example I would like to load the braket package to typset something like \ket{\psi}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, Mathematica has no (La)TeX interpreter. It either can or cannot translate a TeX expression—the concept of loading packages does not apply.  If it cannot, you need to write a custom parser for it, and run that manually.